# Calculate vectorial integrals by their theorems

Tags: integration, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vector-analysis

how are you?

I have this little exercise. It seems to be so easy but I don't know what to do. It's of the topic of **vectorial integrals** (gradient, divergence and curl).

## Calculate the integral  $\int_{} r \cdot \, \vec{dr}$  in a ring of radio *R* that's centered in the origin. Was the result predictable? Explain.

As the statement said, we have to integrate in a ring, that could be seen as an arc. That's a closed curve, so if we now the integral theorem of the gradient, we know that:

> $\int_{c} \vec{F} \cdot \, \vec{dr} =  \int_{c} \nabla \phi \cdot \, \vec{dr} = \int_{} d\phi = \phi_2 - \phi_1$

That's correct if $\vec{F} = \nabla \phi$. But the statements it's not as explicit as I'd like it to be, because I don't know if they want me to do this:

> $\int_{c} r \cdot \, \vec{dr} = \int_{0}^R r \cdot \, \vec{dr}$

Or if they want me to change the coordenates to the cartesian coordenate system. 
I don't know what they want me to demostrate.

Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: UPDATE: Someone told me that the answer is zero, but I don't know if that's the correct answer, and if it is I don't know why, please help me :(

Comment: Hint: At any point on the circle, which direction does $\vec{r}$ point? Which direction does $d\vec{r}$ point?